# Write implications between texts written on more than one line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to write something like:

```
\begin{center}

Proposition A $\implies$ Proposition B $\implies$ Proposition C

\end{center}
```

The only problem is those propositions should be written in two lines, and I don't know how to do that without getting back to the start of the page.
I need to use this with beamer, don't know if it's somehow relevant.
P.S. I solved the problem using matrix environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split one of the propositions over multiple lines, you could use something like a `\parbox` or a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Proposition A $\implies$ Proposition B $\implies$ \parbox{.3\textwidth}{Proposition C very long text and even longer}

\bigskip

Proposition A $\implies$ Proposition B $\implies$ \parbox[t]{.3\textwidth}{Proposition C very long text and even longer}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Propositions}

\begin{align*}
\text{Proposition }A &\implies \text{Proposition }B \\
                     &\implies \text{Proposition }C
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I meant that the single propositions are too long to be written in a single line. I need to write the single propositions in more than one line, but the chain of implications would still be in a single line

Comment: So, you want the line to automatically wrap and be horizontally centered?

Comment: Yeah, I mean something like  "blablabla \\ bla bla" \implies "bla bla bla" where when you go to a new line with \\ I want to be just under the text above